# C# jagged arryay foreach loop

Tags: c#, foreach, jagged-arrays

Can't get my jagged array to output using a nested foreach loop, not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
decimal[][] grades = {
            new decimal []{255628, 89.6m, 90, 82.9m},
            new decimal []{311899, 77.7m, 83.9m, 81.8m, 77},
            new decimal []{314499, 100, 93.7m, 96.7m},
            new decimal []{323345, 62.1m, 55.2m}
        };

        foreach (decimal[] i in grades)
        {
            foreach (decimal [] j in grades)
            {
                textBox1.Text += [i, j] + "\t"; 
            }
        }
        textBox1.Text += "\r\n";


    }
```

Comment: What's `[i, j]` supposed to be? The `foreach`s do the same, not sure if you noted. Did you mean `foreach (decimal j in i)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to read the arrays instead of array elements. See below

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World");

    decimal[][] grades = {
        new decimal []{255628, 89.6m, 90, 82.9m},
        new decimal []{311899, 77.7m, 83.9m, 81.8m, 77},
        new decimal []{314499, 100, 93.7m, 96.7m},
        new decimal []{323345, 62.1m, 55.2m}
    };

    foreach (var i in grades)
    {

            foreach(var k in i){

                Console.WriteLine(k);
            }
            //textBox1.Text += [i, j] + "\t"; 

    }
    //textBox1.Text += "\r\n";



    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have two loops for `grades`?

Comment: @Jonathan i didn't see that extra loop earlier. Modified it.